# REST client using Javascript or Android Native APIs?

Tags: javascript, android, html, security, cordova

I am working on a video app that will deliver **protected video content** for Amazon Fire TV. I am building the User Interface in HTML5, I now have two options for making HTTP REST requests for various APIs:
Either, we can make HTTP requests using **Javascript** or using **Android Native APIs**.

**REST requests through Javascript**
If rest requests are made through Javascript, REST client can easily be ported over to different platforms without any implementation changes. But whats holding back is that JavaScipt is more susceptible to security attacks and app would use security mechanisms to deliver protected content.

**REST requests through Android Native API**
If rest requests are made through native API(using Android Javascript Interface), we lose out the platform agnostic advantage, since REST client would be required to be implemented for different platforms. However, having the REST requests at the native layer facilitates techniques to make the app robust against security attacks.

I need suggestion on as to which approach should one follow in these scenarios.

Comment: "JavaScipt is more susceptible to security attack" -- and your proof of this is, what, exactly? "having the REST requests at the native layer facilitates techniques to make the app robust against security attacks" -- and your proof of this is, what, exactly?

Comment: @CommonsWare The app would call authorization,authentication related APIs, as such would be storing cookies,tokens.Also the app would use device Identity in API calls. With JS debuggers, I believe it is comparatively easy for an attacker to identify this info and then emulate request using this data. Having REST calls using Android Native APIs would then be more secure.